# Specify dependency range in setuptools setup.py

Tags: python, setup.py

I want to specify a version range about my package dependency `marshmallow`, example: `marshmallow 2.x`.

If i set my setuptools setup.py dependency with:

```
marshmallow >2.0.0,<3.0.0a1  # in my setup.py

Best match: marshmallow 2.15.0
Processing marshmallow-2.15.0-py3.5.egg
Removing marshmallow 3.0.0b7 from easy-install.pth file
Adding marshmallow 2.15.0 to easy-install.pth file
```

It is working. How to specify it with less specific version? I explain: if the version `3.0.0a1` is deleted on pypi (possible with an alpha release), the behavior will like (`3.0.0` version don't exist yet)

```
marshmallow >2.0.0,<3.0.0  # in my setup.py

Searching for marshmallow==3.0.0b7
Best match: marshmallow 3.0.0b7
Processing marshmallow-3.0.0b7-py3.5.egg
marshmallow 3.0.0b7 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
```

How to be more simple in `setup.py` to exprime this dependency range like `marshmallow >2,<3`?

Comment: So you want to prohibit any `3.x` including alpha releases?

Comment: @hoefling Yes that's it !

Comment: `marshmallow >2,<3*dev*` should be enough already, if this doesn't help, uninstall the `marshmallow` package first and also remove any `marshmallow` eggs in `.eggs/` directory.